# Не могу перезаписать сообщение telegram bot aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Система должна работать так:
При нажатии на /start должно появиться сообщение "Обратный отсчёт до нового года, господа."
После одной или более секунд оно должно отредактироваться и каждую секунду обновляться с текстом:
До нового года: столько-то времени осталось.
Не могу понять, как сделать.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
import datetime
import asyncio
import time

bot = Bot(token='mytoken')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    message1 = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Обратный отсчёт до нового года, господа.")
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        now = datetime.datetime.today()
        NY = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1)
        d = NY-now
        mm, ss = divmod(d.seconds, 60)
        hh, mm = divmod(mm, 60)
        bot.edit_message_text("До нового года: {} д. {} ч. {} м. {} с.".format(d.days, hh, mm, ss), message.from_user.id)



async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить `await` в свою функцию, а также `message_id` в метод `edit_message`:

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
import datetime
import asyncio
import time

bot = Bot(token='mytoken')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    message1 = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Обратный отсчёт до нового года, господа.")
    # !!! 
    mesagge_object = await message1
    # !!! 
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        now = datetime.datetime.today()
        NY = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1)
        d = NY - now
        mm, ss = divmod(d.seconds, 60)
        hh, mm = divmod(mm, 60)
        await bot.edit_message_text(
            "До нового года: {} д. {} ч. {} м. {} с.".format(d.days, hh, mm, ss),
            # !!!
            message_id=mesagge_object.message_id,
            # !!!
            chat_id=message.from_user.id,
        )


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

P.S.: Рекомендую поподробнее ознакомиться с корутинами в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html).

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с моментом.
Допустим бота запустили 3 пользователя.
Он редактирует сообщение по очереди, т.е. (первый id, второй id, затем третий id, не одновременно всем пользователям)

Comment: Если ответ помог -- отметьте его как решение, пожалуйста.  Вам нужно использовать `async.sleep()` вместо `time.sleep()`. Подробнее смотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729764/asyncio-sleep-vs-time-sleep) + документация из ответа